# Удаление класса JS после заполнения поля

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как **удалить** класс у другого элемента, после того как было заполнен input или textarea?

Т.е. есть:

```
<input class="data" type="text" value="" placeholder="Тест 1">
<input class="data" type="text" value="" placeholder="Тест 2">
<input class="data" type="text" value="" placeholder="Тест 3">
```

И:

```
<a href="#test" class="test no_valide">Тест</a>
```

После того как заполнены все input у ссылки необходимо удалить класс no_valide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На чистом `javascript` -

```js
const inputAll = Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('.required-field'));
const link = document.body.querySelector('.some-link');

inputAll.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('input', requiredField_inputHandler));


function requiredField_inputHandler(){
  if( isInputIsNotEmptyAllValid(inputAll) ){
    link.classList.remove('not-validate');
  }else{
    link.classList.add('not-validate');
  }
}

function isInputIsNotEmptyAllValid( inputAll ){
  let length = inputAll.length;
  
  while(length--){
    let input = inputAll[length];
    
    if( ! input.value ){
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

```css
.not-validate {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="required-field">
<input type="text" class="required-field">
<input type="text" class="required-field">
<a href="#" class="some-link not-validate">some link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9uuhve7g/](https://jsfiddle.net/9uuhve7g/)

Добавь к каждому полю id, чтобы можно было определить когда заполнены именно все.

```
$( ".data" ).change(function() {
if ($('#1').val() != '' && $('#2').val() != '' && $('#3').val() != '') {
  $(".test").removeClass('no_valide');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ищет во всех инпутах, если не пустое поле, то удалить класс из id test

```
$(":input").each(function() {
   if($(this).val() != "")
    ('#test').removeClass('no_valide');
});
```